# jQueryno.Conflict

Tags: joomla1.5, jquery

how to use in joomla no.conflict.

Answer (score 0):

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/scripts/7230

> This plugin is used to load jQuery javascript library, and set "no conflict" mode to allow usage with mootools, and other libraries. No conflict mode removes the "$" operator from jQuery, allowing other libraries to use that operator.